# Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory Exception in Eclipse export jar

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jar

I build a Hibernate+JPA project in Eclipse. It runs fine. Then I want to export it as an executable jar. I got an exception which is same to :[Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory from runnable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143353/unable-to-configure-entitymanagerfactory-from-runnable-jar)

1. This question may very similar to this one: [Unable to configure EntityManagerFactory from runnable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143353/unable-to-configure-entitymanagerfactory-from-runnable-jar)

but it is still unsolved.

2. I did Extract required libraries into generated JAR.
3. I checked that the persistance.xml is in META-INF directory.
4. I added the  org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence in the persistence.xml.
5. I tried to add  property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE" . It does not work.
6. One thing I am not sure. Eclipse and Desktop use the different JVM (32-bit and 64-bit).

Please help! Thank you !

P.S. My reputation is not enough to post image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that EntityManagerFactory does not instantiate, but still don't know how to solve it in Eclipse.

I built an exact same project in Intellij and exported the project as Jar. Now, it works fine.